# Memory leak after calling CGMainDisplayID

Tags: c++, macos, core-graphics

In a pure c++ macos app, I'm querying the available monitors using a simple loop

```
    CGDirectDisplayID mainID = CGMainDisplayID();
    
    uint32 displayCount = 0;
    CGDirectDisplayID displays[8];
    CGGetActiveDisplayList(8, displays.Buffer(), &displayCount);
    
    for (int i = 0, e = displayCount; i < e; ++i)
    {
        CGDirectDisplayID id = displays[i];
        int width = CGDisplayPixelsWide(id)
        int height = CGDisplayPixelsHigh(id));
        ...
    }
```

I capture and report all allocations that I can, and after running my app I get allocations reported in the following stack and many more similar stacks:

```
CGSInternalRegisterNotifyProc in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight @ 0X7FFF5B730000(+0X15B3)
__SLSInitialize_block_invoke in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight @ 0X7FFF5B730000(+0X15E147)
_dispatch_client_callout in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib @ 0X7FFF619C2000(+0X1DB0)
dispatch_once_f in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib @ 0X7FFF619C2000(+0X1D42)
SLSMainDisplayID in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight @ 0X7FFF5B730000(+0X1C6C05)
```

What am I missing to make a clean macos console app? Is there some cleanup function I can call or some event queue I need to flush?

Comment: If you comment out the entire loop, does it still have memory leak?

Comment: Yup, just having a single call the CGMainDisplayID is enough to cause it. The rest of the code just for context I suppose.

Comment: @ChrisSavoie: I'm wondering if you resolve it? Or, in other words, did you find out where those memory leaks were coming from?

Comment: I never resolved it, I just marked it to be ignored by my memory tracking